# Not able to read Azure Key Vault secret value using System Assigned Managed Identity in Azure

Tags: c#, azure

The steps followed:

1. Created a new VM with Enabled Identity (System Assigned)
2. Added the VM in IAM using Role Assignment in storage account
3. Able to generate token using C#
4. For Existing VM Get the managed identity service.
5. Assigned permission to access azure KV using-az keyvault set-policy --name "" --object-id "" --secret-permissions get list
6. Now while executing code from VM I get an error

I'm able to get token from `GetToken()` method but get this error:

```
Unhandled exception. System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at KeyFromAzKeyVault.Program.FatchSecretKeyFromKeyVault(String token)
```

CODE:

```cs
namespace KeyFromAzKeyVault
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var token = GetToken();
            Console.WriteLine(token);
            Console.WriteLine("*************FatchSecretKeyFromKeyVault from KV*********************");
            string key = FatchSecretKeyFromKeyVault(token);
            System.Console.WriteLine(key);
        }

        private static string FatchSecretKeyFromKeyVault(string token)
        {
            WebRequest kvrequest = WebRequest.Create("https://testkvaz203.vault.azure.net/secrets/testsecret/65c8c3b1e56e4a2fae0b6c8033c6b9ce?api-version=7.0");
            kvrequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
            WebResponse response = kvrequest.GetResponse();
            return ParseWebResponse(response, "value");
        }

        private static string GetToken()
        {
            WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://169.254.169.254/metadata/identity/oauth2/token?api-version=2018-02-01&resource=https://vault.azure.net/");
            request.Headers.Add("Metadata", "true");
            request.Method = "GET";
            WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
            return ParseWebResponse(response,"access_token");
        }

        private static string ParseWebResponse(WebResponse response, string tokenName)
        {
            string token = string.Empty;
            using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                StreamReader streamResponse = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.UTF8);
                string stringResponse = streamResponse.ReadToEnd();
                JObject JoResponse = JObject.Parse(stringResponse);
                JValue Jobject = (JValue)JoResponse[tokenName];
                token = Jobject.Value.ToString();
                return token;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to remove the trailing / from the resource query string parameter in the `GetToken()` `WebRequest`.

Change `WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://169.254.169.254/metadata/identity/oauth2/token?api-version=2018-02-01&resource=https://vault.azure.net/");`

to `WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://169.254.169.254/metadata/identity/oauth2/token?api-version=2018-02-01&resource=https://vault.azure.net");`

When I was testing this I got the below JSON error response trying to connect to Key Vault so if the above doesn't work catch the `WebException` and inspect its `Response` property to see if there is any additional detail.

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "Unauthorized",
    "message": "AKV10022: Invalid audience. Expected https://vault.azure.net, found: https://vault.azure.net/."
  }
}
```